# Multiple-step OLE DB error in Visual Basic with .NET

Tags: sql, .net, basic

It's my first programming class, major project for the semester and I am getting this error:

> "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Our code is supposed to submit to an Access database and then pull the information back into a data grid to view.  I've checked that the Access types are set up correctly (some are integer and others short text).
I am not sure how to check 'length' for the data grid as was mentioned in some posts.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub DisplayResults(teamname As String)

    Dim table As New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add("Team Name", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Question 1", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Question 2", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Question 3", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Question 4", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Comments", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Average", GetType(String))

    'Create a connection to the Access database using the 'main' connection string defined in web.config

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("main").ConnectionString)

        ' Create a command that will get results for all teams or the specified team

        Using command As OleDbCommand = connection.CreateCommand

            If TeamNameList2 Is Nothing Then

                ' If a team name wasn't requested, just select all evaluations

                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Evaluation"

            Else

                ' If a team name was selected, make sure we filter for it

                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Evaluation WHERE TeamName = ?"

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", TeamNameList2)

            End If

            connection.Open()

            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

                While reader.Read

                    ' Populate a row in the data container that will be displayed in the grid

                    Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow

                    row("Team Name") = reader("TeamName")
                    row("Question 1") = reader("Question1")
                    row("Question 2") = reader("Question2")
                    row("Question 3") = reader("Question3")
                    row("Question 4") = reader("Question4")
                    row("Comments") = reader("Comments")
                    row("Average") = reader("Average")
                    table.Rows.Add(row)

                End While


                ' Bind the data container to the grid, which causes it to be displayed

                ReportGrid.DataSource = table

                ReportGrid.DataBind()

            End Using

        End Using

    End Using

End Sub
```

Someone asked to post the connection string.  I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but here is some other code that is supposed to update the evaluation:

Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
        ' Create a connection to the Access database using the 'main' connection string defined in web.config

```
    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("main").ConnectionString)

        ' Create a command that will update an evaluation for the specified team

        Using command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Evaluation SET Question1=?, Question2=?, Question3=?, Question4=?, Comments=?, Average=? WHERE TeamName=?", connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question1", Question1.SelectedValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question2", Question2.SelectedValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question3", Question3.SelectedValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question4", Question4.SelectedValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Comments1.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Average", txtAverage.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", Session("EvaluationTeamName"))

            connection.Open()


            ' Execute the command which will actually perform the update in the database

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using
    End Using

    ' Clear the team name so that the evaluation cannot be accidentally taken again
    Session.Remove("EvaluationTeamName")

    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this error occuring on the `using connection` line?

Comment: please explain your problem, what is the error?

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: The error is occurring on the following line:Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

Comment: I added the connection string....does that help identify anything?